# Why is the collection of isomorphism classes of principal G bundles a set?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Given a universal $G$-bundle $EG\longrightarrow{BG}$ it is well known that the set of isomorphism classes of principal $G$-bundles over some space $B$ denote it by $\mathcal{B}(G,B)$ is in bijection with the set of homotopy classes of maps $[B,BG]$, my first question would be: why is $\mathcal{B}(G,B)$ a set?
Is there another way to prove that is indeed a set, or just rather to accept that because of $\mathcal{B}(G,B)\cong[B,BG]$ then it must be a set.
In addition to this, $\mathcal{B}(G,BG)$ would only consists of one isomorphism class right? This would follow from the fact that if $E\longrightarrow{BG}$ is some principal $G$-bundle over $BG$, because of the universality of $EG$ there would only exists a morphism $E\longrightarrow{EG}$ and because they are principal $G$-bundles over the same base space they must be isomorphic.
Does this make sense or did I make a mistake? Thank you for any help and comments.

Answer (score 7):

All $G-$bundles $E$ over some space $X$ have the same cardinality, namely the cardinality of $X \times G$, thus a $G-$bundle $E \rightarrow X$ is isomorphic to $X \times G \rightarrow X$ but where $X \times G$ may have some other topology than the product one, thus the collection of $G-$bundles over $X$ is smaller than or equal in size to the set of topologies on $X \times G$ which in turn has a smaller size than $\mathcal P (\mathcal P (X \times G))$ where $\mathcal P(S)$ denotes the powerset of $S$.

Comment: In your count, you seem to be implicitly asserting that two different principal $G$-bundles have topologically distinct total spaces, but that is not true. For example, $S^2\times\mathbb{RP}^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^2\times\mathbb{RP}^2$ and $\mathbb{RP}^2\times S^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^2\times\mathbb{RP}^2$ are not isomorphic as principal $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundles, but they have homeomorphic total spaces. In this case there are four different principal $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundles over $\mathbb{RP}^2\times\mathbb{RP}^2$, but only three different total spaces up to homeomorphism.

Comment: Alternatively, one can think of cocycles, right? They determine all the classes and form a set.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese No, that's not what I'm implying. If you have two nonisomorphic $G-$bundles $E$ and $E'$ and we choose two fiber and $G-$action preserving bijections $E \rightarrow X \times G$ and $E' \rightarrow X \times G$ the topologies on $X \times G$ induced by these bijections will be nonequal. (1/2)

Comment: Call the two resulting spaces $(X \times G)_E$ and $(X \times G)_{E'}$. If the topologies on them were equal the identity map $(X \times G)_E \rightarrow (X \times G)_{E'}$ would be a $G-$action preserving homeomorphism i.e a bundle isomorphism which would mean that since $(X \times G)_E \approx E$ and $(X \times G)_{E'} \approx E'$ as $G-$bundles that $E \approx E'$ which isn't true. Note that $(X \times G)_E$ and $(X \times G)_{E'}$ may still be homeomorphic, it's just that the two topologies induced on $X \times G$ aren't equal. (2/2)

Comment: @NoelLundström: Ah, I see. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Noel Lundström's answer addresses the first question. As for the second question, your claim is false. We have $\mathcal{B}(BG, G) = [BG, BG]$. If this were a singleton, then $BG$ (and hence $G$) would be contractible: any two maps $BG \to BG$ would be homotopic, in particular $\operatorname{id}_{BG}$ and a constant map.

Your mistake occurs here: "because they are principal $G$-bundles over the same base space they must be isomorphic". That is not true. For example, over $BG$ we have the universal bundle $EG \to BG$, but also the trivial bundle $BG\times G \to BG$. As $EG \to BG$ is the universal bundle, there is map $f : BG \to BG$ such that $f^*(EG) \cong BG\times G$, e.g. a constant map. This doesn't imply that the bundles are isomorphic though as an isomorphism of principal $G$-bundles must cover the identity.